# Reverse-engineer digest http authentication

Tags: ios, hash-functions, api, https-protocol

I have an iOS app which uses digest HTTP authentication with nonce which expires every 5 minutes.

The client calculates response as following:

```
HA1=MD5(username:realm:password)
HA2=MD5(method:digestURI)
response=MD5(HA1:nonce:nonceCount:cnonce:top:HA2)
```

My goal is to figure out the password.

Brute-force attack appears to be unfeasible here. I've also tried to recover the password from the keychain and decrypted app binary/resources. I've also tried to impersonate authentication server to force client to fallback to basic authentication, but it didn't work either. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So finally, I used Cycript and attached to the running app process, and consequently intercepted the private key in runtime.